# Database replication in Kentico 11

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I'm trying to determine if database replication is supported by Kentico 11, I see documentation from 7.0 regarding database replication, but nothing for version 8 onward.  If it is supported, does it only still support merge replication?  We want to have a warm site that runs off of a replicated database that we can fail over to in the case that our primary site is down.

Comment: Are you talking about cloud deployment to Azure? You can have fail-over group without Kentico - azure will do switch for you.

Comment: No, we're not using azure.  We've got an onsite deployment and would like to deploy a separate instance of the site to fail over to.  We've got a SQL server in both locations and would like to point the web server at the failover location at a replicated database.

Answer (score 0):

this was removed from the documentation as it is not related to Kentico. The DB replication or also DB mirroring is SQL server side configuration. If it is configured correctly, Kentico will not even notice that the fail-over DB is used. This is all handled on the SQL server side.